# SQL extra only the day instead of entire date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in my table called created_date. The date format is 2010-02-28. I just wondering is it possible to do a mysql statement, only return the day instead of the entire date. eg. 28

```
SELECT
day(created_date)
FROM
table
```

This above query throw me error, is there a way i can do similar stuff?

cheers

Comment: Yes it is possible. What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: @JW The db i am using is MYSQL JW

Comment: What calendar are you using where `2010-02-32` is a valid date?

Comment: 32. of february? how is that possible?

Comment: Get possibly help from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: @bluebill1049 what error do you get? it looks correct to me, unless your table is really called table, and you need to put backticks around its name

Comment: @fthiella thanks. select extract(day from created_date) as created_day from table this works for me instead

Comment: @bluebill1049 which version of mysql do you have? EXTRACT is correct, but DAY and DAYOFMONTH are equivalent and they should work as well...

Comment: @fthiella o really? it must be the mysql is out date on the server then... thanks mate, i will try on my own server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `MySQL` built-in function called `DAYOFMONTH`

```
mysql> SELECT DAYOFMONTH('2007-02-03');
        -> 3
```

- [DAYOFMONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth)

From Docs,

> Returns the day of the month for date, in the range 1 to 31, or 0 for
>   dates such as '0000-00-00' or '2008-00-00' that have a zero day part.

Answer (score 4):

`MySql` **`EXTRACT`** function extracts day, month or year from a given date.

```
select extract(day from created_date) as created_day from table
```

Comment: `Extract` is the the function you need. Full specs can be found at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_extract.asp).

Answer (score 3):

you can fetch the whole date in your format and display only the required field that is date by using this

```
date("j", strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) );
```